# Warning!! A custom OS can cause critical problems

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I was trying to reboot my Samsung galaxy tab 2 gt p 3100, screen showing massage Warning!! A custom OS can cause critical problems. asking whether you want to download OS or not. so i try to download pushing sound up button then after tab screen showing logo of android downloading. do not turn off target!! for about 15 minutes more. what should i do.  Please help.

Comment: Start the counterpart on your PC to download the ROM you wanted to install? It doesn't fall out of the skies :) // Seriously: You're porblably unaware of what you did, and entered "download mode" instead of starting your device normally. For some background on what that's for, see e.g. our [odin tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info).

Answer (score 2):

Just reboot it, this time without holding a volume button.  Download Mode does nothing unless the device is hooked up to a PC running Odin.